# multiple values in Array ( java )

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

am creating time stamp from an array of string dates `notesTimeStampArray`  and storing the Timestamp(4h , 5h , 3m , 2s  etc)    values into my `arrayList` array and am doing this with this codes:

```
for (int i = 0; i<notesArray.size() && i<notesIDArray.size() ; i++ ){

        try {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

        Date past = format.parse(notesTimeStampArray.get(i));

        Date now = new Date();

        String TimeStamp;

        if ( TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime())  < 60  ) {

        //second
        TimeStamp =  (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + "s");
        arrayList.add(TimeStamp);
        }

        else if (  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime())  >= 60 &&  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime())  < 3600 ) {

        //minute
        TimeStamp =  (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + "m");
        arrayList.add(TimeStamp);

        } else if ( TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime())  >= 3600 &&  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime())  < 86400){

        //hour
        TimeStamp =  (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + "h");
        arrayList.add(TimeStamp);

        } else if ( TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime())  >= 86400 &&  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime())  < 604800 ){

        //day
        TimeStamp =  (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + "d");
        arrayList.add(TimeStamp);


        } else if ( TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime())  >= 604800   ){

        //week
        TimeStamp =  (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime())/7 + "w") ;
        arrayList.add(TimeStamp);
        }

        }
        catch (Exception j){
        j.printStackTrace();
        }

        data.add(current);
        }
```

everything  working fine expect of one thing 
 when am printing the values of both array am getting:

outPut of `notesTimeStampArray` :

```
D/Array =: [Sun Feb 14 23:29:26 GMT+05:30 2016, Sun Feb 14 12:12:47 GMT+05:30 2016, Sun Feb 14 12:11:05 GMT+05:30 2016]
```

outPut of `arrayList`:

```
D/Array2 =: [1m, 1m, 11h, 1m, 11h, 11h]
```

as you can see my total number of items is 3 in my `notesTimeStampArray` but in `arrayList` its 6 i guess am doing something wrong in my loops thats why values are being inserted multiple time but i'm trying to figure out where the real problem is from past 2 hours  but still didnt get anything , if you guys got my mistake then please point it out it'll so helpful for me thanks

Update:

i printed the value of `i` which is in my for loop and the out was :

```
D/i value =: 0
D/i value =: 0
D/i value =: 1
D/i value =: 0
D/i value =: 1
D/i value =: 2
```

means some how the value of `i` is automatically becoming `0` instead of 0 , 1 ,  2  it is 0,0,1,0,1,2,

Comment: Glad to hear you found your problem. Please remember to mark the solution or your question will stay pending as unanswered. For futur post, include more code to make it easier to solve the problem will help you.

Comment: ok i'll keep this in my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all a few things to help you with your code:

1. Try following atleast a few conventions (tab your code in for example)
2. In your if statements and foor loops you are handeling way too many thing. If the first statement didn't catch that the value is under 60, there is no need to check if it is over or equal to 60, because that is already a given thing.
3. Catching Exception is as good as handeling no exceptions (if that is your intention, then thats fine).

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i<notesArray.size(); i++ ){
       try {
           SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
           Date past = format.parse(notesTimeStampArray.get(i));
           Date now = new Date();
           String TimeStamp;

           if ( TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime())  < 60  ) {
               //second
               TimeStamp =  (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + "s");
               arrayList.add(TimeStamp);
           } else if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime())  < 3600) {
               //minute
               TimeStamp =  (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + "m");
               arrayList.add(TimeStamp);
           } else if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime())  < 86400){
               //hour
               TimeStamp =  (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + "h");
               arrayList.add(TimeStamp);
           } else if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime())  < 604800){
               //day
               TimeStamp =  (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + "d");
               arrayList.add(TimeStamp);
           } else {
               //week
               TimeStamp =  (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime())/7 + "w") ;
               arrayList.add(TimeStamp);
           }
       } catch (Exception j){
           j.printStackTrace();
       }
       data.add(current);
   }
   ```

Because I don't really understand your problem, I can only give you the advice to use the debug mode of your IDE. Try adding a Breakpoint to the begining of the for-loop and follow the program step by step.

Comment: hey @aron thanks for responding instead of down voting ,  and thanks for making clean my code but my problem is that i'm getting an output of `D/Array2 =: [1m, 1m, 11h, 1m, 11h, 11h]` extra repeated values instead of `[1m,11h,11h]` because the output of arrayList.size should be same as noteTimeStampArray.size  but  right now its double , i faced this type of problem and reason was that there was an extra for loop (by mistake) inside my loop  but here i  don't know whats the reason of this multiple unexpected values

Comment: hey i updated my question please take a look maybe it'll help you fro tracing down my problem

Comment: Your for-loop looks fine to me, nothing that could cause that problem. The thing is, if you are using the elements of notesTimeStampArray your foor-loop should also be iterating over it to make sure you are not looping too many times. (for(int i = 0; i < notesTimeStampArray.length; i++). Other than that I can't find anything wrong. Must be a problem in your other code. Try adding System.out.println() at multiple locations and try to see if your code is executing the way you expect it to, or use the debug, as recommendet.

Comment: hey i got it ,the problem is in  my different part of code , and their i putted the my array into a for loop by mistake , my bad but thanks a lot for helping